# Need module for notifications like privatemsg

Tags: notifications, privatemsg

I am using Drupal7 and [notification](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) module. Now i want the notification like [Private Message](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module. When any comment occurs or any post occurs at that time i want notification like "Private Message" module i.e. just like "3 new messages" i want same like this "3 new comments" etc..

Can you please inform me if there is any module exists or not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is **messaging_simple**  table which stores message values.

See the column **timeread** this provides time when the message is read. The entries which have **0** value shows unread message.

You can apply sql query to find out rows with timeread **0** for logged in user and can get the count of unread messages.

[image]